# Mod-rewrite - how to make this rule work?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website has one single file that can be called (index.php) and using controllers I can display different pages. This page resides in office/web.

I modified my .htaccess in the following way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

#skip existing files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#everything else goes to index.php
RewriteRule    ^sale/chicago/?$    /office/web/index.php?action=w_filter&type=1&zone=3    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^sale/?$    /office/web/index.php?action=w_filter&type=1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^rent/?$    /office/web/index.php?action=w_filter&type=2    [NC,L]
```

When accessing `http://localhost/office/web/sale/chicago/`, the page loads, so the main rule is working.

However, all the other files required (css, js...) are giving a 404 Not found error.

Using `<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>` inside html file, it expects

```
http://localhost/office/web/sale/chicago/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

The correct URL is:

```
http://localhost/office/web/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

And so on, for all the other media files.

What I need to add/change in my .htaccess to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure `mod_rewrite` based solution that you can avoid to write full path in resources (js, images, images etc):

Add this rule on top of other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(assets/.+?)$ /office/web/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Also please understand that `RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. In your question you have 2 `RewriteCond` only for first rule but next 2 rules don't have it.

As an alternative to adding `RewriteCond` for every rule, you can have this rule **on top** to skip rewrite rules for all files/directories:

```
## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use absolute urls to link js and css.

Instead of

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

try this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/office/web/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Let me know if it's useful.

Comment: Yes, this work. I was already thinking of it. But in this way, every time I will upload the files on the server, I need to change the absolute paths. And this is because this files are actually html templates... I was thinking more on a .htaccess solution. Eventually, I will have to use this.

Comment: @Parkyprg Why changing the absolute path?

Comment: Because on localhost I have /office/web/, but on the server I have a different path for files (eg /web/ only)

Comment: @Parkyprg I had this issue once. Then I learnt to create a subdomain in localhost, eg myweb.localhost.com, which points to /office, so it's the same as in the server..